# JSR-303 validation of abstract field against the constraints in the impl class

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Let's say I have these classes:

```
public class Shop {

    @Valid
    private Fruit fruit;
}

public abstract class Fruit {

     @NotNull
     private String name;
}

public class Apple extends Fruit {

     @NotNull
     private String color;
}

public class Cucumber extends Fruit {

     @Min(0)
     private int lengthInCm;
}
```

when calling validate() on instance of Shop.class I would expect that Cucumber will be evaluated against constraints in Cucumber.class and apples against constraints in Apple.class (of course plus constraints in abstract class for both apples and cucumbers)

How can I achieve this behavior???

Comment: That's exactly the behavior you should get. Do you observe any different behavior?